# Выход из цикла "while True" через проверку ввода

Tags: python, python-3.x

Всем доброго дня! Учусь программировать на Питоне, решил написать простенькую программку, имитирующую игру в города: игрок вводит слово, программа проверяет, есть ли оно в списке и начинается ли оно на ту же букву, на которую кончалось предыдущее слово(в случае если слово кончалось на й,ы,ь,ъ,ц выбирается предыдущая буква) и если слово подошло подбирает ответ. Если игрок хочет выйти, он вводит слово "Закончить". Но с какого-то момента программа начинает воспринимать его как обычное слово, выполняет проверку, пишет, что оно не подходит и не закрывается. Пожалуйста, подскажите, в чем ошибка, код прикладываю. Заранее спасибо.

```python
from random import randint
with open("cities.txt", encoding='utf-8') as city:
    worms=city.readlines()
    words=[]
    for word in worms:
        x=word.replace("\n", "")
        words.append(x)
used=[]
def check(word, previous):
    while previous[-1] in ['ь', 'ъ', 'ы', 'ц', 'й']:
        previous=previous.replace(previous[-1], "")
    if (word in words and word[0].lower()==previous[-1].lower()):
        used.append(word)
        words.remove(word)
        return word
    elif word in used:
        print("Слово уже использовали! (Вам на '" + previous[-1].upper() + "')")
        return check(input(), previous)
    else:
        print("Неправильное слово! (Вам на '" + previous[-1].upper() + "')")
        return check(input(), previous)
def com(prev):
    listing=[]
    while prev[-1] in ['ь', 'ъ', 'ы', 'ц', 'й']:
        prev=prev.replace(prev[-1], "")
    for wor in words:
        if wor[0].lower()==prev[-1].lower():
            listing.append(wor)
    if len(listing)>=1:
        w=listing[randint(0,len(listing)-1)]
        used.append(w)
        words.remove(w)
        return w
    else:
        return "Вы победили!"


prev=words[randint(0, len(words)-1)]
print("Введите 'Закончить' для завершения игры")
fin=False
while True:
    prev=com(prev)
    print(prev)
    if prev=="Вы победили!":
        break
    player=input()
    if player=="Закончить":
        break
    else:
        prev=check(player, prev)
```

Comment: Охх, на "игру в города" уже была [хренова туча вопросов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+игра+в+города), на какой-то даже отвечал.

Comment: О, [нашёл](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1475843/Ошибка-index-error-string-index-out-of-range-при-вызове-переменной-python/1475851#1475851).

Comment: Просмотрел, похожего не нашел, может не заметил. Вопрос скорее не про саму игру в города, а про выход из цикла. Несмотря на то, что условие, описанное в if для выполнения break соблюдается, программа выполняется дальше

Comment: Попробовал поставить `words = ['Москва', 'Питер', 'Краснодар']` вместо чтения из файла, объективно файла у меня нет. При запуске сразу же победил. Довольно трудно читать ваш код, добавление победы в список слов, хмм? Разделите логику игры и проверок, так станет проще. Ну и предполагаю, что в `words` у вас что-то не то. Цикл работает как цикл, тут нечему ломаться.

Comment: Можете на pastebin выложить пример своего файла

Comment: @DiMithras, список городов брал отсюда(https://xn----7sbiew6aadnema7p.xn--p1ai/alphabet.php), каждый город вписан построчно. Проигрыш был засчитан из-за того, что при запуске программа дает ответ на случайный город из списка, а так как ни один из три введенных города не подходят друг к другу, программа в самом начале не может дать ответ. Победы нет в списке слов, она возвращается как результат функции.

Comment: Понимаю, что в цикле ломаться особенно нечему, но и вне его по сути негде, так вся работа выполняется именно в самом цикле, игрок либо вводит "Закончить" и программа закрывается, либо вводит что-то иное, и слово отправляется на дальнейшую обработку. Поэтому очень странно, что после ввода выполнения условия в if выполняется вариант else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так, собрал я себе все города:

```python
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS4

words = list()
url = 'https://города-россия.рф/alphabet2.php?alphabet={}'
for char_ord in range(ord('а'), ord('я')+1):
    response = requests.get(url.format(chr(char_ord)))
    if response.status_code !=200: continue
    soup = BS4(response.content, 'lxml')
    words += [el.text[0:el.text.find('(')-1] for el in soup.find_all('li')[2:]]
```

Немного странный сайт, если пройти по [https://города-россия.рф/alphabet.php](https://xn----7sbiew6aadnema7p.xn--p1ai/alphabet.php), то пишет, мол, города на **А**, а по факту страница содержит неполный список городов на разные буквы. Если пощёлкать по остальным буквам, то ведёт на `alphabet2.php?alphabet=б` и т.д., причём буква **а** выводит нормальный список на букву, если её вставить вручную, а ссылка на странице битая, ведёт на неполный список. Обратим внимание на добавившуюся **2** в ссылке до php.
К тому же сам сайт на странице пишет:

> Вышеперечисленный список может являться неполным, а также иметь некоторые неточности. Если вы заметили ошибки в написании, просим вас сообщить об этом администрации сайта.

> На нашем сайте вы найдете города России, выложенные в алфавитном порядке.

А если провалиться на букву, то надпись уже другая:

> Все города РФ в алфавитном порядке перечислены с указанием области, республики или края, где находится указанный населенный пункт.

Так что, прошёлся по всем буквам, убрал регионы в скобках, получилось **1118** городов. Хотя, если верить [википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0_%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B8#:%7E:text=%D0%9F%D0%BE%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%2025%20%D0%B8%D1%8E%D0%BD%D1%8F,%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC%20%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%88%D0%B5%201%20%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BA), их должно быть 1119… Ну и ладно, близко к этому. Всяко ближе чем 322 города на изначальной странице.

Сохраняем в файл, чтобы сайт больше не мучать:

```python
with open('cities.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for word in words:
        f.write(word+'\n')
```

Хотя я бы рекомендовал серилизованно в JSON хранить, 14KB вместо 20KB:

```
import json
with open('cities.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(words, f, ensure_ascii=False)
```

И читать потом проще `with open('cities.json', 'r') as f: words = json.load(f)`

---

## Пробуем ваш код

Теперь попробовал скопипастить полностью код без изменений, с сохранённым txt, вывод:

```
Введите 'Закончить' для завершения игры
Радужный
Йошкар-Ола
Неправильное слово! (Вам на 'Н')
Нагорный
Неправильное слово! (Вам на 'Н')
Нальчик
Калач-на-Дону
Закончить
```

Т.е. на "Закончить" цикл закончился. Обидно, что вы исключили букву "й", т.к. есть Йошкар-Ола, но выход из цикла работает. Думаю при названии города есть смысл сразу предлагать на какую букву надо назвать, чтобы не было путаницы с й.

Что остаётся посоветовать.

Смотрите в дебагере, что у вас приходит в программу, когда пользователь пишет "Закончить", может кодировка или спец. символы какие, поэтому `if` не отрабатывает.

Более надёжным (и привычным!) способом для консольных приложений будет обёртка в [`KeyboardInterrupt`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#KeyboardInterrupt):

```python
try:
    while True:
        prev=com(prev)
        …
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("That's all, folks!")
```

Так выполнение цикла должно закончиться по <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, либо же при нажатии на <kbd>⏹</kbd> (interrupt the kernel) в Jupyter Notebook.

Ещё более элегантным решением будет обернуть `input()` в [`Signal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html), хотя бы потому, что не надо делать дополнительные отступы с try / except, и просто добавить в начале кода:

```python
import signal
def handle_interrupt(signum, frame):
    print("\nИгра завершена. Спасибо за игру!")
    exit(0)
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handle_interrupt)
```

И, напоследок, т.к. Python иногда творит чудеса с буфером, возможно перед `input()` стоит сделать `sys.stdin.flush()`, но, опять же, пройдитесь дебагером. Если вместе с `input()` прилетает какая-то хрень из-за буферов, это должно помочь.

Comment: Огромное спасибо за помощь с выходом и советы в целом, выход заменю, буду знать теперь.